# Assign users to group in django via HTML template and not via admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have created a django app in which users can register via SignUp Form. I have created two groups `Admin Users` and `Staff Users`. When any user signs up he is not allocated to any of the group. I want to create a webpage where all the users will be displayed and there should be a drop-down in front of user names which will let the logged in user (a member of `Admin User` group, I will restrict this page to `Admin Users` group only) to select the group among the available groups. In simple words any member of group `Admin User` should be able to add any other member who is not assigned to any group. I need a basic help on how the views.py and HTML page should be look like.

Comment: If you want any more clarification on question please ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did exactly something similar not long ago.
Here's the model, form and view. Ask if anything is not clear.

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class Personnel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other fields

class AddPersonnelToGroupForm(forms.Form):
    personnels = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Personnel.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={"class" : "form-control select-multiple"}))

def add_personnels_to_group(request, pk): # pk is group's pk
    """Recursively add personnels to a group"""
    template = "personnel/add_personnels_to_group.html"
    group = Group.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPersonnelToGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            personnels = [Personnel.objects.get(pk=pk) for pk in request.POST.getlist("personnels", "")]

            for personnel in personnels:
                user = personnel.user
                if user.groups.filter(id=group.id).count():
                    user.groups.remove(group)
                else:
                    user.groups.add(group)
                    msg.append("{} added".format(personnel.display_name))

            return redirect(wherever)
    else:
        form = AddPersonnelToGroupForm()
        return render(request, template, {"form" : form, "group" : group})
```

Edit

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class Personnel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other fields

class AddPersonnelToGroupForm(forms.Form):
    personnels = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Personnel.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={"class" : "form-control select-multiple"}))
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Group.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class" : "form-control select-multiple"})
    )

def add_personnels_to_group(request): # pk is group's pk
    """Recursively add personnels to a group"""
    template = "personnel/add_personnels_to_group.html"
    # group = Group.objects.get(pk=pk) # replace this 

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPersonnelToGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            group = form.cleaned_data['group'] # replacement
            personnels = [Personnel.objects.get(pk=pk) for pk in request.POST.getlist("personnels", "")]

            for personnel in personnels:
                user = personnel.user
                if user.groups.filter(id=group.id).count():
                    user.groups.remove(group)
                else:
                    user.groups.add(group)
                    msg.append("{} added".format(personnel.display_name))

            return redirect(wherever)
    else:
        form = AddPersonnelToGroupForm()
        return render(request, template, {"form" : form, "group" : group})
```

So in your template for the form you need to have to fields

```
{{ form.group }}
{{ form.personnels }}
```

Comment: Consider accepting this as the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I saw your answer now.Sorry for delay in accepting the answer

Comment: The template is very simple. Just a simple `{{ form.personnels }}` and django will render it with a `selectmultiple` widget so that you can select more than one `personnel` by holding `ctrl` and clicking. If you've ever worked with django forms then you should just copy any of it and replace the form fields.

Comment: So by this the users can be assigned to a particular group as selected in dropdown ?

Comment: I am kinda new to django.I have made some basic forms like login etc.But I was clueless about how to go with this case of mine

Comment: try taking the django tutorial. helped me a lot